# Recommended Data Visualization for Webpage with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visualization, data-visualization

Goal:
Visualize data that Y is amount of quantity and for the X is the date.

Problem:
Do you have a recommended data visualization tool for jquery?

The request is to enable to click on the colored block and you will retrieve a tooltip or something about amount of .....
and a list that should be displayed below the graph.

Do you know any data visualization that you can recommend me?

A concrete example that fit to the criteria is the Stackoverflow's graph.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed). If you are looking for simple to use, this is probably your best bet. If you are looking for more customization, I recommend you take a look at [d3](http://d3js.org/).